# Do we say "she gave a lip service when she did her work" to say that she did her work with little effort?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Some people just do their work superficially or they did not put 100% of their effort into doing the work and the product or the result that they created is often of low quality.

Do we say "**she gave a lip service when she did her work**" to say that she does her work with little effort?

**If we can't say that, what is a better way to express that someone makes little effort to do things?**

Comment: She gave lip service; you don't use the indefinite article 'a' before 'lip'.

Comment: "doed" is incorrect.  The past tense of "do" is "did"

Answer (score 1):

**Lip service** implies the expression of support for something.

If she *spoke about* the importance of her work, but then did it poorly or with little gusto, you might say she paid lip service to its importance.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lip) has examples of its use.

We generally **pay** lip service to something, rather than **give** it. (Though **give** is a little more common in the US than in the UK.)

There are many ways to say someone makes little effort. You might say he/she does it sporadically, when it suits him/her, half-heartedly, lazily, carelessly, shoddily, inattentively, without enthusiasm....

Comment: **gave lip service** is less common, but it's not unheard of: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paid+lip+service%2Cgave+lip+service&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpaid%20lip%20service%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgave%20lip%20service%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @stangdon Thanks. That's true, though it rarely appears in dictionaries. Looking into this a bit more, I found that while a Google Books (1 Jan 1941 – 31 Dec 1964) search for **gave lip service** returns 26 pages of hits,  **"gave lip service" Congress** returns 21 of them! The 5 pages that _don't_ mention Congress seem to be mostly from _other_ US publications together with some Canadian and a few New Zealand ones. So perhaps we can say that **gave lip service** is used chiefly outside the UK. If you agree I'll edit my answer to mention this.

Comment: I'm not sure if the **gave** version is as un-UK as all that, but this Ngrams search definitely implies that in the UK, **pay** is much more common, while in the US, it's only moderately more common: give lip service:eng_us_2019,give lip service:eng_gb_2019,pay lip service:eng_us_2019,pay lip service:eng_gb_2019

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, lip service refers to words without actions.

Some expressions which have the meaning you intend are:

- [Phoning it in](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phone_in)

> (idiomatic) To fulfill a responsibility with a minimum effort rather than the appropriate level of effort.

- A [perfunctory](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perfunctory) effort

> Done only or merely to conform to a minimal standard or to fulfill a protocol or presumptive duty.

Answer (score -2):

Your initial query of doing a poor job in little time is classic lip service.

But your later question about accomplishing the job while expending little effort is not necessarily lip service at all. If the person manages to do all that is expected but it doesn't take that person much effort, that is not lip service at all.

"Lip service" is much more about the quality of the final output rather than how much time it takes. Although if the person does put in a lot of effort but the product is still lousy, that too isn't lip service. That's just a lousy job.

Comment: No - [lip service](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lip-service) would mean _saying_ that you were in favour of doing something but not making any effort to do it.